# Finding Conditional Distribution of Multivariate distribution

Tags: multivariable-calculus, normal-distribution

> Q: Supposing y ~ N4 (µ,∑) and
>
> µ = (1 2 3 -2)'
>
> ∑ =\begin{pmatrix}
>         4 & 2 & -1 & 2\\
>         2&6&3&-2\\
>         -1&3&5&-4 \\
>         2 &-2 &-4 &4\\
>         \end{pmatrix}

What is

(i)   f(y1 | y2, y3, y4)?

(ii) 12|34 ?

For (i), I am using the formula E(y|x) = µ_y + σ_yx '∑_xx^(-1)(x - µ_x)

where I let x = (y_2 y_3 y_4). What happens to my ∑_xx now? I would believe it is a partition of the current ∑ where taking the values from row 2 to row 4 and column 2 to column 4. But if I am taking that, then there is no sense in making it a conditional probability in the first place.

Please help. Thanks

Comment: "...then there is no sense in making it a conditional probability...". Why not? Perhaps you should look at a simpler problem first: What happens if you ignore the last two components, that is, you look at $w\sim N_2(w_1,w_2)$ with $\mu_w=(1,2)$ and $\Sigma_w$ equal to the $2\times2$ submatrix in the upper left corner. Then what is the distribution of $w_1$ given $w_2$? **Hint**: It is **not** the same as the unconditional distribution of $w_1$.